# Bootstrap radio buttons pre-select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm using Bootstrap for a new project and I'm about to build a form with it. I've created two radio buttons ('Yes' and 'No') with JS (see example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons)) and now I want to pre-select one of those radio buttons. I already tried:

```
selected = "selected"
```

and

```
checked = "checked"
```

But the buttons are not highlighted. You can only see the attribute in the source code and not on the GUI. Here is what I did for for the buttons (taken from the examples):

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
    <label for="commentsAllowed">Comments allowed</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Yes
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> No
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do you know how I can solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this to highlight option1 in bootstrap , provided that you have a default checked value in your radio input

```
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').parent('label').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. But I have three groups of radio buttons - now only the last group gets activated with this line. // Edit: My bad, I've used the same names. Thank you so much!

Comment: try to change `$('input[type="radio"]:checked')` that fits your case